# Programa que abre Bloco de Notas em segundo plano

Tags: c#, windows

Preciso fazer um programa que, ao usuário apertar um botão, o programa abra o bloco de notas e insira uma mensagem previamente programada por mim no código. Como eu poderia fazer a parte do programa inserir o texto da mensagem no Bloco de Notas?

Comment: Então coloque o que você já fez e qual problema está enfrentando.

Answer (score 3):

O seguinte código abre o Bloco de Notas e insere um texto dentro:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

static void AbrirBlocoDeNotasComTexto(string texto)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad");
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    Process notepad = Process.Start(startInfo);
    notepad.WaitForInputIdle();

    IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), null, null);
    SendMessage(child, 0x000c, 0, texto);
}
```

[Tirei daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30219618/1314276).